# How to make a react component that can be rendered with no data and later rendered with data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a situation that I'm sure is common and I just haven't learned the react way for accomplishing it. Let's say I have this:

```
var appView = new React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SomeSubview/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(
    React.createElement(appView),
    $('#app').get(0)
);
```

My question is how should I create the `SomeSubView` react component so that it can render properly without any data, and then later render showing some data when the data is available. I have pub/sub system set up, so I'd like to be able to subscribe to an event and get the data to `SomeSubView` that way. `SomeSubView` might look something like this:

```
SomeSubView = new React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        pubsub.subscribe({
            callback: function() {
                // something the sets the state or a prop of this component
            }
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        // something that renders properly when 
        // there is no data and renders the data when there is data
        return (
            <div></div>
        )
    }
});
```

I can't tell if this a case for state or props on the react component? I don't know if it's best practice to put conditionals in the render function?

Comment: state is the one you need.

Comment: Yeah, put the data in the `state` of `SomeSubView`. And yes, typically, `render` is conditional depending on `props` and `state`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SomeSubView just check if data is available in your render function, but before returning the markup.

Like this:

```
SomeSubView = new React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        pubsub.subscribe({
            callback: function() {
                // something the sets the state or a prop of this component
            }
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        // something that renders properly when 
        if( this.state.data.length > 0 ){
            var data = <li>{this.state.data}</li>;
        }

        return (
            <div>{data}</div>
        )
    }
});
```

If the variable data is not set, React will simply pass over it as non-existent.

You can of course also use .map() on your state data to loop out markup just like in most render examples.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use state like user3728205 said, [especifically](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) setState().

> `setState(function|object nextState[, function callback])`
>
> Merges nextState with the current state. This is the primary method
>   you use to trigger UI updates from event handlers and server request
>   callbacks.
>
> The first argument can be an object (containing zero or more keys to
>   update) or a function (of state and props) that returns an object
>   containing keys to update.
>
> Here is the simple object usage...
>
> `setState({mykey: 'my new value'});`

What this says is that "whenever" you update your state via setState, React will execute the method render again for you. So, you should put yor display logic based on the state, when it changes the view displayed will change too.

I say "whenever" because React doesn't fire re-render immediatily, but creates a pending state transition.

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.
>
> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState
>   and calls may be batched for performance gains.
>
> setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional
>   rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable
>   objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state
>   differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

For more information about the magic of React you should read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html).
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

A [simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielgiussi/y0a2k7ox/1/) that maybe can help.
And i recommend read the flux architecture that is very easy to understand and implement (is about utilizing a unidirectional data flow), and you have implementations like [Fluxxor](http://fluxxor.com/) that facilitates the use of flux. This is for your pubsub part.